# Javascript: Div slide down on another div

Tags: javascript, jscript

In this jsfiddle, I would like the "#video" div to slide down completely and stay until the mouse is over "#wrap". But its going up and down even though the mouse is on #wrap. Any idea?

html:

```
<div id="wrap">
<div id="text">text</div>
<div id="video">video</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#text
{
position: absolute;
top:20px;
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
background: #FAAC58;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#video
{
position: absolute;
top:20px;
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
display:none;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
```

Jscript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#wrap").mouseover(function(){
    $("#video").slideDown("slow");
         });
    $("#wrap").mouseout(function(){
    $("#video").slideUp("slow");
         });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZyUYN/1045/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when `#video` slides down, it comes on `#wrap` so mouse pointer becomes on `#video` then `$("#wrap").mouseout` is triggered

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#wrap").mouseover(function(){
    $("#video").slideDown("slow");
         });
    $("#video").mouseout(function(){
    $("#video").slideUp("slow");
         });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `hover` event instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`, your `mouseover` get triggered many times as the mouse moves inside the div `#wrap`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#wrap").hover(function () {
        $("#video").slideDown("slow");
    }, function () {
        $("#video").slideUp("slow");
    });
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L5fatyjk/)

Answer (score 0):

use mouseenter and mouseleave instead.  It will handle the mouseover bubbling (https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/)

Answer (score 0):

The `mouseover()` and `mouseout()` functions are called continuously when the mouse is moving. Try instead using [`mouseenter()`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseout()`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) so that the event is only fired once:

```
$("#wrap").mouseenter(function() {
    $("#video").slideDown("slow");
});
$("#wrap").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#video").slideUp("slow");
});
```

Here's a link to [an updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZyUYN/1047/).

Answer (score 0):

When your #video div covers up the #wrap div, it triggers the mouseout event. One option is to use a third see-through div above both #video and #wrap and use that to trigger the events:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="text">text</div>
    <div id="video">video</div>
    <div id="cursor"></div>
</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#cursor").mouseover(function(){
   $("#video").slideDown("slow");
  });
  $("#cursor").mouseout(function(){
   $("#video").slideUp("slow");
  });
 });
```

Here's the updated working code: http://jsfiddle.net/tf4qhoxs/